# Get rid of spaces and tabs in wmic output

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Using batch, trying to get output of the following command:

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename
```

Thus, I'm simply doing the following:

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename >>"C:\out.log"
```

Unfortunately, this is the output I'm getting:

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from WMIC is unicode, your "spaces" are nulls from the two bytes unicode characters in file. Try with

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename | find /v "" >>"C:\out.log"
```

Comment: Thanks, best solution in my case as I wanted to add more info to log.

Answer (score 3):

`wmic` has an output flag that you can use in place of redirect symbols that might work out better for you.

```
wmic /output:"C:\out.log" logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename
```

Comment: There is the `/Append` switch that works almost the same as output but it appends. Plus you can specify `clipboard` instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem seeing the file, but when doing `findstr`, I noticed it is not found.  So I did the following and it will allow it to produce a regular ASCII text file.

Another solution is to type out the file and do it again

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,volumename >>"C:\out.log"
type c:\out.log > c:\out1.log
findstr  "your text" out1.log (instead of out.log)
```